# Representing int with 8 bits in python's byte array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, encoding, decoding

I need a buffer (list of bytearray) with a length of 50 (nodes in my network, irrelevant), but I need exactly 8 bits to represent the byte array, what I have now is:

```
buffer = []
for position, nodeID in enumerate(range(128,128+50)):
 print(bin(int(bytearray([nodeID]).hex(), base=16)).lstrip('0b'))
 buffer.append(bytearray([nodeID]))
 print(buffer[-1])
print(buffer)
```

What I am doing now is setting the leftmost position to 1 so I get exactly 8 bits, I need this layout for a certain decoding process. My question is : is there a more efficient way to have a list like that? i.e:
A list of 50 bytearrays, with each byte array set to the index+1 (node.id).
I want to omit the ones in the beginning yet still want the data to be represented in exactly 8 bits.

output:

> 10000000 bytearray(b'\x80') 10000001 bytearray(b'\x81') 10000010
> bytearray(b'\x82') 10000011 bytearray(b'\x83') 10000100
> bytearray(b'\x84') 10000101 bytearray(b'\x85') 10000110
> bytearray(b'\x86') 10000111 bytearray(b'\x87') 10001000
> bytearray(b'\x88') 10001001 bytearray(b'\x89') 10001010
> bytearray(b'\x8a') 10001011 bytearray(b'\x8b') 10001100
> bytearray(b'\x8c') 10001101 bytearray(b'\x8d') 10001110
> bytearray(b'\x8e') 10001111 bytearray(b'\x8f') 10010000
> bytearray(b'\x90') 10010001 bytearray(b'\x91') 10010010
> bytearray(b'\x92') 10010011 bytearray(b'\x93') 10010100
> bytearray(b'\x94') 10010101 bytearray(b'\x95') 10010110
> bytearray(b'\x96') 10010111 bytearray(b'\x97') 10011000
> bytearray(b'\x98') 10011001 bytearray(b'\x99') 10011010
> bytearray(b'\x9a') 10011011 bytearray(b'\x9b') 10011100
> bytearray(b'\x9c') 10011101 bytearray(b'\x9d') 10011110
> bytearray(b'\x9e') 10011111 bytearray(b'\x9f') 10100000
> bytearray(b'\xa0') 10100001 bytearray(b'\xa1') 10100010
> bytearray(b'\xa2') 10100011 bytearray(b'\xa3') 10100100
> bytearray(b'\xa4') 10100101 bytearray(b'\xa5') 10100110
> bytearray(b'\xa6') 10100111 bytearray(b'\xa7') 10101000
> bytearray(b'\xa8') 10101001 bytearray(b'\xa9') 10101010
> bytearray(b'\xaa') 10101011 bytearray(b'\xab') 10101100
> bytearray(b'\xac') 10101101 bytearray(b'\xad') 10101110
> bytearray(b'\xae') 10101111 bytearray(b'\xaf') 10110000
> bytearray(b'\xb0') 10110001

Comment: Can we get example input and output?

Comment: For binary `0/1` format of an int, you can use `format`. You can also specify how many digits it should output: `format(node_id, "08b")`

Comment: @flakes, I have attached it.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you want. Do you want a list of bytearray, each of length 1, with a single byte with a value greater than 0x80, in sequence +1?

Comment: @Keith and then the question would be, **but why**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, I also have that question, but decided to just take the question at face value.

Comment: What do you mean by "exactly 8 bits to represent the byte array"? A byte array is *much* bigger than 8 bits. An *individual* byte is always 8 bits, regardless of content.

Comment: @keith yes, you guessed right. And to why I need this : this is a specific format for a decoder that I designed on another platform so I need a matching array for said format.
But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a list of length 50 with a single byte bytearray with value of index + 0x80, this will do it:

```py
l_of_ba = [bytearray([i + 0x80]) for i in range(50)]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.